# Creating installation directory "/tmp/" on guest failed: VERR_NOT_FOUND. - So, how to upgrade Virtualbox guest additions via terminal?

Tags: 22.04, virtualbox, guest-additions

Today, as I started my Virtualbox VM and tryed to enabled the second screen, I found out the button to enable it has "grayed out" and cannot be clicked. It was working until yesterday.

I have made some research and found out several threads (i.e. [this one](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?t=104564#:%7E:text=Re%3A%20Virtual%20Screen%202%20%22Enable%22%20Greyed%20Out&text=Start%20the%20VM%20from%20full,the%20Power%20Off%20option%20set.)) indicating the problem could lie on the VM Guest Additions. Actually, other functionality such as the copy-paste between the host and guest OS are disabled.

So I have tryed to update Virtualbox Guest Additions from the VM top menu (Devices > Upgrade Guest Additions), but I am getting this popup error:

```
Creating installation directory "/tmp/" on guest failed: VERR_NOT_FOUND.


Result Code:
VBOX_E_IPRT_ERROR (0X80BB0005)
Component:
GuestSessionWrap
Interface:
IGuestSession {234f0627-866d-48c2-91a5-4c9d50f04928}
```

I have checked that directory /tmp/ exists on my machine, but I guess for some reason it cannot download the new intallation files there.

So I want to update Virtualbox Guest Additions via terminal.

How can I do it?

### What I tried

By following [this tutorial](https://www.linuxtechi.com/install-virtualbox-guest-additions-on-ubuntu/?utm_content=cmp-true), I have tryed to reinstall the guest additions anew

```
sudo apt update
```

here I get the message

```
4 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them
```

and then this error message:

```
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:5 and /etc/apt/sources.list:50
W: Target Packages (main/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:5 and /etc/apt/sources.list:50
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:5 and /etc/apt/sources.list:50
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:5 and /etc/apt/sources.list:50
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:5 and /etc/apt/sources.list:50
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:5 and /etc/apt/sources.list:50
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:5 and /etc/apt/sources.list:50
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (main/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:5 and /etc/apt/sources.list:50
W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:5 and /etc/apt/sources.list:50
W: Target DEP-11-icons-hidpi (main/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:5 and /etc/apt/sources.list:50
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:5 and /etc/apt/sources.list:50
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:5 and /etc/apt/sources.list:50
W: Target Packages (restricted/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:5 and /etc/apt/sources.list:50
W: Target Packages (restricted/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:5 and /etc/apt/sources.list:50
W: Target Packages (restricted/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:5 and /etc/apt/sources.list:50
W: Target Translations (restricted/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:5 and /etc/apt/sources.list:50
W: Target Translations (restricted/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:5 and /etc/apt/sources.list:50
W: Target DEP-11 (restricted/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:5 and /etc/apt/sources.list:50
W: Target DEP-11 (restricted/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:5 and /etc/apt/sources.list:50
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (restricted/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:5 and /etc/apt/sources.list:50
W: Target DEP-11-icons (restricted/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:5 and /etc/apt/sources.list:50
W: Target DEP-11-icons-hidpi (restricted/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:5 and /etc/apt/sources.list:50
W: Target CNF (restricted/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:5 and /etc/apt/sources.list:50
W: Target CNF (restricted/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:5 and /etc/apt/sources.list:50
E: The repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-security Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:48 and /etc/apt/sources.list:51
W: Target Packages (main/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:48 and /etc/apt/sources.list:51
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:48 and /etc/apt/sources.list:51
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:48 and /etc/apt/sources.list:51
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:48 and /etc/apt/sources.list:51
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:48 and /etc/apt/sources.list:51
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:48 and /etc/apt/sources.list:51
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (main/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:48 and /etc/apt/sources.list:51
W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:48 and /etc/apt/sources.list:51
W: Target DEP-11-icons-hidpi (main/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:48 and /etc/apt/sources.list:51
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:48 and /etc/apt/sources.list:51
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:48 and /etc/apt/sources.list:51
W: Target Packages (restricted/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:48 and /etc/apt/sources.list:51
W: Target Packages (restricted/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:48 and /etc/apt/sources.list:51
W: Target Packages (restricted/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:48 and /etc/apt/sources.list:51
W: Target Translations (restricted/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:48 and /etc/apt/sources.list:51
W: Target Translations (restricted/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:48 and /etc/apt/sources.list:51
W: Target DEP-11 (restricted/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:48 and /etc/apt/sources.list:51
W: Target DEP-11 (restricted/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:48 and /etc/apt/sources.list:51
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (restricted/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:48 and /etc/apt/sources.list:51
W: Target DEP-11-icons (restricted/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:48 and /etc/apt/sources.list:51
W: Target DEP-11-icons-hidpi (restricted/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:48 and /etc/apt/sources.list:51
W: Target CNF (restricted/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:48 and /etc/apt/sources.list:51
W: Target CNF (restricted/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:48 and /etc/apt/sources.list:51
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:5 and /etc/apt/sources.list:50
W: Target Packages (main/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:5 and /etc/apt/sources.list:50
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:5 and /etc/apt/sources.list:50
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:5 and /etc/apt/sources.list:50
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:5 and /etc/apt/sources.list:50
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:5 and /etc/apt/sources.list:50
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:5 and /etc/apt/sources.list:50
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (main/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:5 and /etc/apt/sources.list:50
W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:5 and /etc/apt/sources.list:50
W: Target DEP-11-icons-hidpi (main/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:5 and /etc/apt/sources.list:50
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:5 and /etc/apt/sources.list:50
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:5 and /etc/apt/sources.list:50
W: Target Packages (restricted/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:5 and /etc/apt/sources.list:50
W: Target Packages (restricted/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:5 and /etc/apt/sources.list:50
W: Target Packages (restricted/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:5 and /etc/apt/sources.list:50
W: Target Translations (restricted/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:5 and /etc/apt/sources.list:50
W: Target Translations (restricted/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:5 and /etc/apt/sources.list:50
W: Target DEP-11 (restricted/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:5 and /etc/apt/sources.list:50
W: Target DEP-11 (restricted/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:5 and /etc/apt/sources.list:50
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (restricted/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:5 and /etc/apt/sources.list:50
W: Target DEP-11-icons (restricted/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:5 and /etc/apt/sources.list:50
W: Target DEP-11-icons-hidpi (restricted/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:5 and /etc/apt/sources.list:50
W: Target CNF (restricted/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:5 and /etc/apt/sources.list:50
W: Target CNF (restricted/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:5 and /etc/apt/sources.list:50
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:48 and /etc/apt/sources.list:51
W: Target Packages (main/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:48 and /etc/apt/sources.list:51
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:48 and /etc/apt/sources.list:51
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:48 and /etc/apt/sources.list:51
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:48 and /etc/apt/sources.list:51
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:48 and /etc/apt/sources.list:51
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:48 and /etc/apt/sources.list:51
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (main/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:48 and /etc/apt/sources.list:51
W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:48 and /etc/apt/sources.list:51
W: Target DEP-11-icons-hidpi (main/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:48 and /etc/apt/sources.list:51
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:48 and /etc/apt/sources.list:51
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:48 and /etc/apt/sources.list:51
W: Target Packages (restricted/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:48 and /etc/apt/sources.list:51
W: Target Packages (restricted/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:48 and /etc/apt/sources.list:51
W: Target Packages (restricted/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:48 and /etc/apt/sources.list:51
W: Target Translations (restricted/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:48 and /etc/apt/sources.list:51
W: Target Translations (restricted/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:48 and /etc/apt/sources.list:51
W: Target DEP-11 (restricted/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:48 and /etc/apt/sources.list:51
W: Target DEP-11 (restricted/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:48 and /etc/apt/sources.list:51
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (restricted/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:48 and /etc/apt/sources.list:51
W: Target DEP-11-icons (restricted/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:48 and /etc/apt/sources.list:51
W: Target DEP-11-icons-hidpi (restricted/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:48 and /etc/apt/sources.list:51
W: Target CNF (restricted/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:48 and /etc/apt/sources.list:51
W: Target CNF (restricted/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:48 and /etc/apt/sources.list:51
```

so I run

```
apt list --upgradable
```

and get

```
tommaso@tommaso-VirtualBox:~$ apt list --upgradable
Listing... Done
gjs/jammy-updates 1.72.4-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 1.72.2-0ubuntu2]
libgjs0g/jammy-updates 1.72.4-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 1.72.2-0ubuntu2]
transmission-common/jammy-updates,jammy-updates 3.00-2ubuntu2.1 all [upgradable from: 3.00-2ubuntu2]
transmission-gtk/jammy-updates 3.00-2ubuntu2.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 3.00-2ubuntu2]
```

then

```
sudo apt install build-essential linux-headers-$(uname -r) -y
```

VM top menu > Guest Additions CD Image, and it seems that nothing is happening, but I guess that is so because they are already installed, but not updated.

```
cd /media/<MY_USER>/VBox_GAs_7.0.4/
sudo ./VBoxLinuxAdditions.run
```

but I get

```
Cannot reload kernel modules: one or more modules is still in use
```

so I reboot my VM, and then run `sudo ./VBoxLinuxAdditions.run` again but nothing changes.

I have updated VirtualBox application, but that does not solve the problem.

Comment: With your normal user (which should have sudo privilege) try `cd /media/your_cd_rom_path ; bash ./autorun.sh`.

Comment: @FadKad thanks, it runs with no error but it does not solve the problem. I still cannot copypaste, enable the second screen, ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the guest additions could not properly get installed because of

1. the not upgraded apt packages
2. the duplicated lines in `/etc/apt/sources.list`

these two issues prevented the file `VBoxLinuxAdditions.run`  to be generated in the install directory `/dev/cdrom` of guest additions as I tryed to virtually insert and mount the gust additions CD from the Virtualbox topbar menu "Device".
This was probably the error showed by the Virtualbox UI popup.

I have solved these problems by

### 1 - upgrading the packages

```
apt list --upgradable
```

and then running

```
sudo apt upgrade <PACKAGE>
```

for every "first level directory" of the paths returned by the previous command, following the dependency order (skip a package if it returns error, go on with the next one, then come back).

e.g.
 `gjs/jammy-updates 1.72.4-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 1.72.2-0ubuntu2]`
 --> `sudo apt upgrade gjs`

### 2 - removing the duplicated lines in /etc/apt/sources.list

```
sudo vim /etc/apt/sources.list
```

and then commente lines 50 and 51, as indicated by

```
W: Target CNF (restricted/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:5 and /etc/apt/sources.list:50
[...]
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:48 and /etc/apt/sources.list:51
```

### 3 - retrying installing Virtualbox Guest Additions

```
sudo apt update
```

which returns no more warings, then

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

then restart the VM via `sudo reboot`.

Then, from the VirtualBox topbar "Device" menu -> Click "Insert guest additions CD" (it does not seem like it does anything, but it does indeed)

finally

```
sudo mkdir -p /mnt/cdrom
sudo mount /dev/cdrom /mnt/cdrom
cd /mnt/cdrom
sudo ./VBoxLinuxAdditions.run
```

go on when it asks if you want to install the guest additions even if they are already on the OS, and again restart the VM via `sudo reboot`.

And this time I see the previously disabled options are back to work.